# How to deploy a Laravel vue3 inertia after run npm build i get the file which is public/build/asset. My problem is how to arrange this files in cpanel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade

I want someone to help me please.

When i host i want to access both frontend and backed works. Please I need someone to help how to arrange this folders in public/build/asset so that it may work on my server. I use WordPress server